# Count number of WHERE filters in SQL query using regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

Update: I've updated the test string to cover a case that I've missed.

I'm trying to do count the number of `WHERE` filters in a query using regex.

So the general idea is to count the number of `WHERE` and `AND` occuring in the query, while excluding the `AND` that happens after a `JOIN` and before a `WHERE`. And also excluding the `AND` that happens in a `CASE WHEN` clause.

For example, this query:

```
WITH cte AS (\nSELECT a,b\nFROM something\nWHERE a>10\n AND b<5)\n, cte2 AS (\n SELECT c,\nd FROM another\nWHERE c>10\nAND d<5)\n SELECT CASE WHEN c1.a=1\nAND c2.c=1 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' \nEND,c1.a,c1.b,c2.c,c2.d\nFROM cte c1\nINNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.a = c2.c\nAND c1.b = c2.d\nWHERE c1.a<4 AND DATE(c1)>'2022-01-01'\nAND c2.c>6

-- FORMATTED FOR EASE OF READ. PLEASE USE LINE ABOVE AS REGEX TEST STRING
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT a,b 
  FROM something 
  WHERE a>10 
    AND b<5
)

, cte2 AS (
  SELECT c,d
  FROM another
  WHERE c>10
    AND d<5
)

SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN c1.a=1 AND c2.c=1 THEN 'yes'
      WHEN c1.a=1 AND c2.c=1 THEN 'maybe'
      ELSE 'no'
  END,
  c1.a,
  c1.b,
  c2.c,
  c2.d
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte2 c2
   ON c1.a = c2.c
  AND c1.b = c2.d
WHERE c1.a<4
  AND DATE(c1)>'2022-01-01'
  AND c2.c>6
```

should return `7`, which are:

1. `WHERE a>10`
2. `AND b<5`
3. `WHERE c>10`
4. `AND d<5`
5. `WHERE c1.a<4`
6. `AND DATE(c1)>'2022-01-01'`
7. `AND c2.c>6`

The portion `AND c1.b = c2.d` is not counted because it happens after `JOIN`, before `WHERE`.

The portion `AND c2.c=1` is not counted because it is in a `CASE WHEN` clause.

I eventually plan to use this on a Postgresql query to count the number of filters that happens in all queries in a certain period.

I've tried searching around for answer and trying it myself but to no avail. Hence looking for help here. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this job. It is going to be very difficult to handle all the edge cases (aggregate filters, text values with the word "where" are two obvious ones). If you actually want to get an accurate count then you are going to have to do some basic parsing. If you can extract just the where clauses that will make it easier.

Comment: @RichardHuxton what do you mean by "basic" parsing? if there is a way that I can extract all the `WHERE` clauses in the query I'll be more than happy to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to stay away from lookarounds as they could be messy and too painful to use, especially with the fixed-width limitation of lookbehind assertion.

My proposed solution is to capture all scenarios in different groups, and then select only the group of interest. The undesired scenarios will still be matched, but will not be selected.

1. Group 1 - Starts with `JOIN` (undesired)
2. Group 2 - Starts with `WHERE` (desired)
3. Group 3 - Starts with `CASE` (undesired)

```
(JOIN.*?(?=$|WHERE|JOIN|CASE|END))|(WHERE.*?(?=$|WHERE|JOIN|CASE|END))|(CASE.*?(?=$|WHERE|JOIN|CASE|END))
```

Note: Feel free to replace `WHERE|JOIN|CASE|END` to any keyword you want to be the 'stopper' words.
[image]

All scenarios including the undesired ones will be matched, but you need to select only Group 2 (highlighted in orange).

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. Only one it couldnt catch was if queries used subqueries instead of cte. Nonetheless I think it's good for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/4WkEHory):

```
WITH DataSource (parts) AS 
(  
  SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(
    'WITH cte AS (SELECT a,b FROM something WHERE a>10 AND b<5)\n, cte2 AS (SELECT c,d FROM another WHERE c>10 AND d<5)\n SELECT c1.a,c1.b,c2.c,c2.d FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.a = c2.c AND c1.b = c2.d WHERE c1.a<4 AND c2.c>6',
    E'(?= WHERE)[^)|;]+'
  ,'gmi'
  ) 
)
SELECT SUM
       (
           (length(parts[1]) - length(REPLACE(parts[1], 'AND', ''))) / 3 -- counting ANDs
            + 1 -- for the where
      )
FROM DataSource
```

The idea is to match the text after `WHERE` clause:

[image]

and then simply count the ANDs and add one because of the matched WHERE.

Comment: thanks! The answer is really close, but it missed some cases (my bad, my test string above was not comprehensive enough). It wasn't able to handle cases where there is a closing bracket `)` during the `WHERE` filter clause. Example: `WHERE a>1 AND DATE(b)>'2023-01-01' AND c>4`. I've changed my test string to cover this weakness. Apologies for the changes.

Comment: Does this work if I have `SELECT 'WHERE IS THE ANSWER?''` or `SELECT thing FROM some_table WHERE condition ORDER BY (col_a || ' AND ' || col_b)` ?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I guess they do not, but based on what I see from my samples, the ones you suggested are kinda edge cases so I'm ok with the regex not working for your cases. Cheers.